# Instagram post Photo through their API

Tags: php, image, instagram, instagram-api

i want to post images to my Instagram account through PHP,i have searched this a lot and found that Instagram do not allow posting photos from their APIs but those posts i read were old 1 year or 2 ago,i have found some non-official APIs but someone said they may close my account. my question now is:do Instagram still do not allow this till today ?

Comment: Take a look at this:https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API

Comment: @Cosmin_Victor thanks a lot for your reply , i found it already during my search but it is private API, and he said he wrote it cause they blocked his device and his accounts :D , and someone mentioned that using such apis may block my account which is my company official account :D .